# Where is the Windows Sourcecode located?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

As you know, the European Union has forced Microsoft to release the Windows XP Source Code.
I want to make my own OS and I thought this was a good source.
But where is the source code?

I have already looked at the Microsoft website but I have not found anything.

I can't find it anywhere.
Can anyone help?

Edit: This is an old question, it blew up at the leak of the windows source code. But please note that using any unlicensed source code from Microsoft is illegal, as it is copyright infringement.

Comment: There is a leaked source of Windows XP sp1 now.

Comment: @Llallum A YouTuber called NTDEV posted a video on compiling the Windows XP source code. Microsoft flagged that video. The link on 4chan is removed. So, only the people who downloaded the source code right when the link was provided was able to get the source code.

Comment: @HyperCreeck I saw that video but there are also other people uploaded the same video. The link can still be found in torrent sites.

Comment: @Llallum but torrenting isn't a bit of legal advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Windows is not fully open source but they moved some codebase to github: see: https://github.com/microsoft/ or https://microsoft.github.io/windows/

I guess if you want to write your own OS you copy from Linux: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode

Comment: That link specifically says source code is **not** required.